# os.listdir( path ) возвращает удаленные файлы

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, path

Решил написать скрипт чтобы из 100+ html файлов вытащить весь текст.

Из одного из них я вручную собрал текст и сохранил в той же директории, но перед самым запуском скрипта - удалил.
Когда скрипт запустился `os.listdir()` стабильно возвращает этот файл.

Я думаю, что это кэш, но не знаю как это решить в коде и можно ли это как то упредить в будущем?

P.S. Запускал и без PyCharm, напрямую основным интерпретатором - та же ошибка.

P.S.S. Я удалил директорию, удалил файл в оригинале этой директории и скопировал эту директорию снова в папку с проектом, но ошибка сохранилась

Comment: Как вы удаляли файл? Каким редактором редактировали?

Comment: Записал файл с помощью SublimeText а удалил выбрав файл в проводнике windows и нажав delete

Comment: Как вы проверили что файл ещё тут? По имени в списке или по содержимому (лишние слова в результате)?

Comment: Ваш скрипт читает другую директорию, не ту где вы правите файлы.

Comment: `os.listdir()` вернул список в котором среди прочего был этот файл

Comment: Только что проверил пути. Скрипт читает именно эту директорию. К тому же в проекте это единственная директория кроме `venv` и результата работы. То есть хочу сказать, что я решил проблему просто костыльной проверкой `если не .txt`, а если бы читал другую директорию, то так бы не получилось

Comment: Со всем уважением, но не верю вам. Всегда такие проблемы заканчиваются "ой да я тут сделал копию, а скрип читал из текущей директории, а она другая оказалась".

Comment: Я вас абсолютно понимаю, поэтому сам старательно проверил подобные глупости перед тем как задать вопрос. Я сталкивался с проблемами аля "Ой, скрипт читал не ту директорию", но к моему удивлению - это не тот случай. Я лишь хотел разобраться в интересной ошибке, но в скрипте могу оставить костыль, все таки скрипт для себя, а не для заказчика. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Это не может быть интересная ошибка. Файловые системы никогда ничего не кэшируют способом, который может заметить пользователь или прикладной программист. Ищите ошибку в использовании.